# Python randomize but repeat an element every two elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to shuffle a list with some elements repeating every two elements.

I have a list containing repeating elements that looks like this:

mylist = [**A**, **A**, **A**, B, C, D, E, F]

I would like to randomly shuffle the list but make sure that all the repeated elements are two elements apart from each other, like the one below.

mylist = [**A**, B, C, **A**, D, E, **A**, F]

So far I've only figured out the below code to check if two elements are repeating right after another or are one element apart, but I don't know how to make sure they are exactly two elements apart.

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
      if mylist[i] == mylist[i+1] or mylist[i] == mylist[i+2]:
      mylist.append(mylist.pop(i))
```

Comment: How would you do it if it were not Python? (e.g. imagine shuffling a deck of cards and making sure that an Ace is at every third position) - here's what I would do: (1) remove the A's, (2) shuffle the rest; (3) insert the A's at the desired positions

Comment: Do you mean that all repeated elements are atleast two apart from eachother? furthermore in your example mylist is not shuffled?

Comment: @joostblack Thanks for the quick response. I want them to be exactly two apart, so they also can't have more than 2 between them.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That is a great suggestion. Do you think it'll work even if all A, B, and C have repeats? My actual list has 100 items and almost half of them are repeating.

Comment: Yes I think it will work (if you do it right).

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the shuffle function yourself and place items as groups in the resulting list.  Each item is expected to take positions that are 2 steps apart within the remaining positions. Note that this may lead to situations where there is no room left to place a group of items so you will need to loop until a valid shuffle is found.   Processing by groups from largest to smallest should converge much faster than merely checking random shuffles.

```
from random import choice
from collections import Counter

def shuffle(arr,step=3):
    counts    = Counter(arr)              # number of repetitions of each letter
    result    = [None]*len(arr)           # will fill positions as we go
    positions = set(range(len(arr)))      # unfilled positions
    while positions:                     
        for v,count in counts.most_common(len(counts)):  # largest to smallest
            ranges = (range(i,i+count*step,step) for i in range(0,len(mylist)-count+1))
            available = [r for r in ranges if positions.issuperset(r)]
            if not available:
               positions = set(range(len(arr)))  # no room left for group 
               break                             # try again
            for p in choice(available):          
                result[p] = v             # fill group positions
                positions.discard(p)      # remove from remaining positions
    return result
```

output:

```
mylist = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

print(shuffle(mylist))    
# ['A', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'D']
print(shuffle(mylist))
# ['A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'B']
print(shuffle(mylist))
# ['B', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'A']


mylist = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E","E","E", "F","B","B","B","B"]

print(shuffle(mylist))
# ['C', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'B']
print(shuffle(mylist))
# ['B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'A']
print(shuffle(mylist))
# ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D']
```